# Passing multiple complext types to WCF Rest

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am writing a WCF Rest service, I have a function where i need to upload a file and some data.

the question is, is it possible to pass mulitple complex types plus a stream to a single WCF Rest function? if yes does any one have any good examples?

so for instance

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadSomething/")]
    public void UploadSomething(ComplexType ctype, DifferentType dtype, Stream fileContent)
    {

    }
```

Comment: When you have Stream as a parameter you cannot pass another parameter along with it. Rather you can create a complex type that encloses other complex types along with a memory stream parameter that you can use to upload your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have Stream as a parameter you cannot pass another parameter along with it. Rather you can create a complex type that encloses other complex types along with a memory stream parameter that you can use to upload your file.

Ex:

```
public class UploadObject
{
    public ComplexType cType {get;set;}
    public DifferentType dType {get;set;}
    public MemoryStream fileStream {get;set;}
}
```

And now use that in your service as shown:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadSomething/")]
public void UploadSomething(UploadObject uploadObj)
{

}
```